# TypeError: DataLoader found invalid type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

> TypeError: DataLoader found invalid type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Hi everyone, I have encountered difficulties, I can't find a solution, please help.

The program encountered an error at the train_fn () function.

## train.py

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import joblib
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
# from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader
from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader
from model import *
from Constant import *
import os
print(os.getcwd())
# path = '/home/ktcodes/jktModel/data/a09'
path = './data/a09'

e2e_emb = joblib.load(f'{path}/e2e_emb.pkl.zip')
c2c_emb = joblib.load(f'{path}/c2c_emb.pkl.zip')
skill_prob = joblib.load(f'{path}/skill_prob.pkl.zip')

filtered_skill_prob = {}
channel = 10
for i, skill_id in enumerate(skill_prob.index):
    if len(skill_prob[skill_id])>= channel:
        filtered_skill_prob[skill_id] = skill_prob[skill_id]
joblib.dump(filtered_skill_prob, f'{path}/filtered_skill_prob.pkl.zip')


# normalization
scaler = StandardScaler()
all_c_v = []
for k,v in c2c_emb.items():
    all_c_v.extend(list(v.numpy()))
all_c_v = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(all_c_v).reshape(-1,1))
all_c_v1 = {}
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(c2c_emb.items()):
    all_c_v1[k] = all_c_v[i*10:(i+1)*10].reshape(-1,)
all_e_v = {}
for skill,qu_embs in e2e_emb.items():
    q_num = qu_embs.shape[0]
    temp_all_v = qu_embs.numpy().reshape(-1,)
    temp_all_v = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(temp_all_v).reshape(-1,1))
    all_e_v[skill] = temp_all_v.reshape(-1,10)



skill_emb = {}
for skill in tqdm(filtered_skill_prob.keys()):
    temp_c = (np.array(all_c_v1[skill]))
    temp_e = np.array(np.mean(all_e_v[skill], axis=0))
    skill_emb[skill] = np.append(temp_c, temp_e)
prob_emb = {}
for skill in tqdm(filtered_skill_prob.keys()):
    for i, prob in enumerate(filtered_skill_prob[skill]):
        temp_c = (np.array(all_c_v1[skill]))
        temp_e = (np.array(all_e_v[skill][i]))
        new_emb = np.append(temp_c, temp_e)
        if prob in prob_emb.keys():
            prob_emb[prob] = np.row_stack((prob_emb[prob], new_emb)).squeeze().astype(np.int32)
#             print(prob_emb[prob].shape)
        else: prob_emb[prob] = new_emb
for prob in tqdm(prob_emb.keys()):
    if len(prob_emb[prob].shape) > 1:
        prob_emb[prob] = np.mean(prob_emb[prob], axis=0)



# Train/Test data
read_col = ['order_id', 'assignment_id', 'user_id', 'assistment_id', 'problem_id', 'correct', 
            'sequence_id', 'base_sequence_id', 'skill_id', 'skill_name', 'original']
target = 'correct'
# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}/skill_builder_data.csv', low_memory=False, encoding="ISO-8859-1")[read_col]
df = df.sort_values(['order_id', 'user_id'])
# delete empty skill_id
df = df.dropna(subset=['skill_id'])
df = df[~df['skill_id'].isin(['noskill'])]
df.skill_id = df.skill_id.astype('int')
print('After removing empty skill_id, records number %d' % len(df))

# delete scaffolding problems
df = df[df['original'].isin([1])]
print('After removing scaffolding problems, records number %d' % len(df))

#delete the users whose interaction number is less than min_inter_num
min_inter_num = 3
users = df.groupby(['user_id'], as_index=True)
delete_users = []
for u in users:
    if len(u[1]) < min_inter_num:
        delete_users.append(u[0])
print('deleted user number based min-inters %d' % len(delete_users))
df = df[~df['user_id'].isin(delete_users)]
df = df[['user_id', 'problem_id', 'skill_id', 'correct']]
print('After deleting some users, records number %d' % len(df))
# print('features: ', df['assistment_id'].unique(), df['answer_type'].unique())

df = df[df['skill_id'].isin(filtered_skill_prob.keys())]
df['skill_cat'] = df['skill_id'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['e_emb'] = df['problem_id'].apply(lambda r: prob_emb[r])
df['c_emb'] = df['skill_id'].apply(lambda r: skill_emb[r])

group_c = df[['user_id', 'c_emb', 'correct']].groupby('user_id').apply(lambda r: (np.array(r['c_emb'].tolist()).squeeze(), r['correct'].values))
train_group_c = group_c.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=2020)
test_group_c = group_c[~group_c.index.isin(train_group_c.index)]
joblib.dump(train_group_c, f'{path}/train_group_c.pkl.zip')
joblib.dump(test_group_c, f'{path}/test_group_c.pkl.zip')

# print(type(train_group_c))
# # print(train_group_c.values)
# userid = train_group_c.index
# print(userid)
# q, qa = train_group_c[userid[0]]
# print(q, qa)

train_dataset = DKTDataset(train_group_c, max_seq=MAX_SEQ)
train_dataloader  = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
valid_dataset = DKTDataset(test_group_c, max_seq=MAX_SEQ)
valid_dataloader  = DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = DKT(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim, device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(
    optimizer, max_lr=MAX_LEARNING_RATE, steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataloader), epochs=EPOCHS
)

model.to(device)
criterion.to(device)


for epoch in (range(EPOCHS)):
     # there
    loss, acc, auc = train_fn(model, train_dataloader, optimizer, criterion, device)
#     print("epoch - {}/{} train: - {:.3f} acc - {:.3f} auc - {:.3f}".format(epoch+1, EPOCHS, loss, acc, auc))
    loss, acc, pre, rec, f1, auc = valid_fn(model, valid_dataloader, criterion, device)

    res = "epoch - {}/{} valid: - {:.3f} acc - {:.3f} pre - {:.3f} rec - {:.3f} f1 - {:3f} auc - {:.3f}".format(epoch+1, EPOCHS, loss, acc, pre, rec, f1, auc)
    print(res)
```

The program does not go to this function：

```py
def train_fn(model, dataloader, optimizer, criterion, scheduler=None,  device="cpu"):
    print('enter...')
    print("dataloader", type(dataloader))
    model.train()
    train_loss = []
    num_corrects = 0
    num_total = 0
    labels = []
    outs = []

    for x_emb, q_next, y in (dataloader):
        x = x_emb.to(device).float()
        y = y.to(device).float()
        q_next = q_next.to(device).float()
        
        out = model(x, q_next).squeeze().astype(np.int32)#[:, :-1]
        
        loss = criterion(out, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
#         scheduler.step()
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        
        target_mask = (q_next!=0).unique(dim=2).squeeze().astype(np.int32)
#         target_mask = (y!=-1)
    
        filtered_out = torch.masked_select(out, target_mask)
        filtered_label = torch.masked_select(y, target_mask)
        filtered_pred = (torch.sigmoid(filtered_out) >= 0.5).long()
        
        num_corrects = num_corrects + (filtered_pred == filtered_label).sum().item()
        num_total = num_total + len(filtered_label)

        labels.extend(filtered_label.view(-1).data.cpu().numpy())
        outs.extend(filtered_pred.view(-1).data.cpu().numpy())

    acc = num_corrects / num_total
    auc = roc_auc_score(labels, outs)
    loss = np.mean(train_loss)

    return loss, acc, auc
```

Error info:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/kt/jktModel/embedding_dkt.py in <module>
    145 for epoch in (range(EPOCHS)):
    146     print("ashkdgjggvnskaj")
--> 147     loss, acc, auc = train_fn(model, train_dataloader, optimizer, criterion, device)
    148 #     print("epoch - {}/{} train: - {:.3f} acc - {:.3f} auc - {:.3f}".format(epoch+1, EPOCHS, loss, acc, auc))
    149     loss, acc, pre, rec, f1, auc = valid_fn(model, valid_dataloader, criterion, device)

~/kt/jktModel/model.py in train_fn(model, dataloader, optimizer, criterion, scheduler, device)
    110     model.train()
    111     train_loss = []
--> 112     num_corrects = 0
    113     num_total = 0
    114     labels = []

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    519             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    520                 self._reset()
--> 521             data = self._next_data()
    522             self._num_yielded += 1
    523             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    559     def _next_data(self):
    560         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 561         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    562         if self._pin_memory:
    563             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     50         else:
     51             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 52         return self.collate_fn(data)

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py in __call__(self, batch)
     32             return type(elem)(*(self(s) for s in zip(*batch)))
     33         elif isinstance(elem, Sequence) and not isinstance(elem, str):
---> 34             return [self(s) for s in zip(*batch)]
     35 
     36         raise TypeError(f'DataLoader found invalid type: {type(elem)}')

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     32             return type(elem)(*(self(s) for s in zip(*batch)))
     33         elif isinstance(elem, Sequence) and not isinstance(elem, str):
---> 34             return [self(s) for s in zip(*batch)]
     35 
     36         raise TypeError(f'DataLoader found invalid type: {type(elem)}')

~/anaconda3/envs/dkt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_geometric/loader/dataloader.py in __call__(self, batch)
     34             return [self(s) for s in zip(*batch)]
     35 
---> 36         raise TypeError(f'DataLoader found invalid type: {type(elem)}')
     37 
     38     def collate(self, batch):  # Deprecated...

TypeError: DataLoader found invalid type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I have no ideas. This has already plagued me for a few days.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly late, but in case anyone else encounters a similar issue - `torch_geometric.loader.DataLoader` cannot handle `numpy` arrays, so you must convert them to `torch.Tensor` in your dataset first. Alternatively, you could pass a custom collate function to the dataloader.

In this particular case, your `DKTDataset` returns tuples `x_emb, q_next, y`, some of which are of type `numpy.ndarray`, so convert them to tensors in `DKTDataset.__get__()`.